# Flatness of a simple ring extension

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, flatness

Assume $A \subseteq B=A[b]$ are integral domains, $b \in B$ is algebraic over $A$ (but not necessarily integral over $A$), and $A$ and $B$ have the same field of fractions. 
(Notice that $b=u/v$ for some $u, v \in A$).

I do not mind to further assume that: $A$ and $B$ are noetherian, $\mathbb{C} \subset A$, $B$ is a UFD (but I do not want to assume that $A$ is a UFD), $B$ is regular (but I do not want to assume that $A$ is regular), $B$ is separable over $A$, and if it helps I agree to assume that $b$ is integral over $A$.

My question: I wish to show that $B$ is flat over $A$.
(Notice that if $B$ is flat and integral over $A$, then it is faithfully flat over $A$, and then since $A$ and $B$ have the same field of fractions, it follows that $A=B$).

I have tried to show flatness using the follwong ideas:

(1) [Corollary 9 (and Theorem 5)](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0021869380902331/1-s2.0-0021869380902331-main.pdf?_tid=6dd51f92-0ee8-11e5-891e-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1433882894_d5a067da80e0cde84dc079fb65c3e751) of Wang.
But the problem is that $A$ is not a UFD, so $B$ is not isomorphic to $A[Z]/(vZ-u)$, but to $A[Z]/(h_1,\ldots, h_m)$.

(2) [Lemma 1 (with Theorem 1)](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-04/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1.pdf) of Richman.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you take  $A=\mathbb{C}[t^2-1,t(t^2-1)]\subset B= \mathbb{C}[t]$ (the normalization of an ordinary double point), aren't all your hypotheses fulfilled?

Comment: @abx: Thanks. From your point of view you are right; however, I have in mind a specific example in which it is not clear if $B$ is flat over $A$ or not.  So maybe my question is misleading.